# LINQ query to Sum value over date ranges

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to create a linq query that would produce a collection of date ranges with sums of the Capacity value taking into the account that ranges can overlap and I'd like a sum and a distinct date range for that overlapping periods. Thanks.

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<Capacities> _list = new List<Capacities>{
               new Capacities {StartDate = DateTime.Parse("01/01/2013"), StopDate = DateTime.Parse("01/01/2013 06:00"), Capacity = 100},
               new Capacities {StartDate = DateTime.Parse("01/01/2013 04:00"), StopDate = DateTime.Parse("01/02/2013 00:00"), Capacity = 120},
               new Capacities {StartDate = DateTime.Parse("01/04/2013"), StopDate = DateTime.Parse("01/04/2013 15:00"), Capacity = 100},
               new Capacities {StartDate = DateTime.Parse("01/04/2013 15:00"), StopDate = DateTime.Parse("01/04/2013 18:00"), Capacity = 150}
            };
            //results expected
            //01/01/2013 00:00 - 01/01/2013 04:00   100
            //01/01/2013 04:00 - 01/01/2013 06:00   220
            //01/01/2013 06:00 - 01/02/2013 00:00   120
            //01/04/2013 00:00 - 01/04/2013 15:00   100
            //01/04/2013 15:00 - 01/04/2013 18:00   150
            return View();
        }

        public class Capacities
        {
            public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
            public DateTime StopDate { get; set; }
            public int  Capacity {get;set;}
        }
```

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have a solution with loops and want to transform it into LINQ? Would you accept a solution without LINQ?

Comment: Hoping to replace some old code that would traverse the set and split the overlapping ranges and then traverse that to sum capacities creating new array. Yeah, I was looking for a linq query. Thanks.

Comment: I think I can come up with some LINQ, but it will not be pretty. The former solution is probably more comprehensible.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I may just have to dress up my old code a bit if a linq query is to complex.

Comment: It's a good question but I don't think LINQ is the appropriate tool here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did some programming, but I extended your code quite a bit. But I was able to use LINQ in the very end :-)

my code:

```
SortedSet<DateTime> splitdates = new SortedSet<DateTime>();
foreach (var item in _list)
{
    splitdates.Add(item.Period.Start);
    splitdates.Add(item.Period.End);
}

var list = splitdates.ToList();
var ranges = new List<DateRange>();
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count - 1; i++)
    ranges.Add(new DateRange() { Start = list[i], End = list[i + 1] });

var result = from range in ranges
             from c in _list
             where c.Period.Intersect(range) != null
             group c by range into r
             select new Capacities(r.Key.Start, r.Key.End, r.Sum(a => a.Capacity));
```

Complete code is here: http://pastebin.com/wazbb1r3
Note that the output differs because of locale. Also, some bits are not necessary like DateRange.Contains().

On the two loops above, I have no idea how to transform them to LINQ in a readable manner.

Comment: +1 for the interesting approach (even though I didn't try the code myself ;). But I'm wondering if there might be a general solution to such problems because a scenario like this seems to be common to time tables / schedules. E.g. Interval from Noda Time doesn't have methods to check intersections which might be helpful.

Comment: Fantastic!  This is ideal. That DateRange class is very handy and I really appreciate the linq clause.